# Differentiation of a vector product

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I have a function $\phi(r,t)=p(r) \cdot k(t) $

What would be $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} $ ?

Can I rewrite it this way: $ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial(p(r) \cdot k(t))}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial p(r)}{\partial r} \cdot k(t)  $  ?

Comment: If you expand the dot product using coordinates, *there* you can apply the product rule, and see that in the end it amounts to what you suggest.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean *dot product* - aka *inner product*.

Comment: Yes, I meant inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost true. Since you are in a chart other terms might appear because a scalar product is defined with a metric $g_{ij}p^i k^j$. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ this amounts to

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(A(r)\cdot B) = B \cdot \frac{\partial A(r)}{\partial r} + B\times \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\times A(r)\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: How did you get that? Is it some known rule?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities you can derive it by going into a chart and grouping it back together.

Comment: I found this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Dot_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions Which article is wrong? ;/

Comment: I have found this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Dot_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions Which article is wrong? ;/